Error in Epush server while logging into account
I'm facing nearly same issue. But, my server is Digital Ocean.
I'm getting
http://128.199.85.126:8080/iclock/ProcessWebSiteRequest.aspx?EPS=1.01 NOT FOUND error for this api. I've reviewed the code and tried every possible solution, but haven't got any lead. Pleas if someone finds the solution let me know.
tomcat-error
java-version
epush

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
